# Malloc doesn't doesn't add new memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm having trouble when I try to use malloc to allocate new space for floats inside my array.
My goal is to dynamically create array, and malloc to add a space for new float each time I want to add a new float.

Here is the code I am trying to run, but each time it only allocates an array with sizeof(float), even though the variables keep increasing.

```
float *funkcia_e(FILE **subor, int *pocet_cien) {
float *pole_cien;
*pocet_cien = 1;

    while (fgets(nazov, sizeof nazov, *subor) != NULL)
    {
        pole_cien = (float*) malloc((*pocet_cien) * 4);

        fscanf(*subor, "%f", &pole_cien[pozicia++]); //This causes problems

        *pocet_cien = *pocet_cien + 1;
    }
}
int main() {
    int pocet_cien = 1;
    float *pole_cien = NULL;

    funkcia_r(&subor, pole_cien, &pocet_cien);
}
```

Here is the recorded debugging: https://s.put.re/RR6wqRk.mp4

It appears the malloc actually corrupts the array, instead of exntending it. Any ideas?

Comment: cant afford to realloc, as I have to allocate the array dynamically and realloc would purge the contents of array when reallocating it.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: "cant afford to realloc, as I have to allocate …" - read the documentation before blindly assuming something!

Comment: still, realloc would need me to define the array beforehand, which I am not allowed to.

Comment: Each new `malloc()` does not initialize any of the data. This code throws away your previously read data.  It also leaks memory abominably. You **need** to use `realloc()` because it preserves the previously initialized data from the array; but you should avoid incrementing the space used by 1 on each reallocation — that can lead to bad (quadratic) performance. (You have a contrarian understanding of what `realloc()` and `malloc()` do — _'It appears the malloc actually corrupts the array, instead of extending it'_ is wrong; `malloc()` allocates new space whereas `realloc()` extends old space).

Comment: Well you took the [tour], now read [Ask], and [MCVE]. The code you posted is not an MCVE, your `main` calls `funkcia_r`, but you have given us `funkcia_e` as an example. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: malloc allocates a new array, it does not extend an array. So at the end, you have a brand new array, which has its last element set, and none of the others.

Comment: You seem to think that malloc does what realloc actually does, and think that realloc does what malloc actually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `realloc`. It does what you wanted `malloc` to do, i.e. lets you extend a previously allocated block. In contrast, `malloc` is a one-shot deal: you get your memory block, and that's what you have to work with.

> (from the comment) cant afford to `realloc`, as I have to allocate the array dynamically and `realloc` would purge the contents of array when reallocating it.

That is not true: when `realloc` extends the amount of memory allocated to your program, and decides that it must re-allocate the block, it *copies* the content of the current block into the new block, up to the allocated size of the old block, so the new block is ready to use. Hence, your current program results in a memory leak.

In order to let `main` use results of allocation you must pass the pointer `pole_cien` by pointer, i.e. as `float**`. Otherwise the results of assigning it inside `funkcia_e` are not propagated to `main`.

A few other points to consider:

- Do not cast `malloc` results
- Do not hard-code size of `float` as `4`; use `sizeof(float)`
- Make sure `pocet_cien` starts at zero, and use it in place of `pozicia`; add `1` on the call to `realloc`.

Comment: On the basis of the "get it right before you make it fast" principle, this is good.  Then the code should be upgraded so that it doesn't increment the amount of space by one `float` on each iteration. For example, it should double the amount of allocated space, keeping track of what's allocated and what's used separately.  This can help avoid quadratic copying behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite obvious as malloc does not "add" any memory, but allocates a new chunk of it - every time fresh. So eventually you  access not allocated memory and you get the memory fault as index increments all the time but you allocate the space for 4 elements.